# Is there any way to avoid momentary display of HTML source code in TinyMCE Text Area?

Tags: html, tinymce, textarea

One of the application is loading few images using URL in TinyMCE Text area. 
When page loads, momentarily it shows HTML source code of the textarea and then HTML Output gets displayed.

Sequence of events is mentioned below: 
1] User Hits url www.testurlforexplaination.com 
2] User request to pre-populate data in HTML form
3] HTML Form consists of Text Area, Tiny MCE Rich Text Area, Radio Buttons, Check Box and Buttons. 
4] User Momentarily sees HTML Source code in Tiny MCE Text area (before complete page gets loaded) 
5] Once page is completely loaded, user sees desired HTML output with pre-populated data.

Step#4 mentioned above confuses USER with the impression that some error occurred. 
Is there any way to avoid momentary display of HTML source code in Tiny MCE Text Area?

Comment: are you using the regular tinymce build or the jQuery tinymce build?

Answer (score 2):

if you have multiple tinymce editors, I believe you have multiple inits (for each textarea)

set initial property of the textarea linked to tiny mce to hidden (preserve the space)

```
<textarea id ="txtarea1"cols="20" rows="20" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

and when on load completed of the tinymce content, show it.

```
// Add an observer to the onLoadContent event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
...
elements :"txtarea1",
setup : function(tmced) {
tmced.onLoadContent.add(function(tmced, obj) {
 $('.txtarea1').show();

});
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna, as suggested I tried tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
 readonly : true, 
    plugins : 'autoresize,inlinepopups',
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    content_css : '/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css',
    autoresize_min_height: 80,
    autoresize_max_height: 400,
    setup : function(tmced) {
tmced.onLoadContent.add(function(tmced, obj) {
tmced.show();
});
}
}); But It's not working.  FYI: There are 6 TinyMCE Text Areas in the form.

Comment: Thanks Krishna for sharing solution, but it's not working. As suggested, visibility of the textarea remains hidden. It looks like  tinyMCE is overridding JS

Comment: can you put a alert before and after the show() call. Also does the error console say anything... tiny mce shouldnt override, we are adding a new hook to onLoadContent...

Comment: Hi Krisha, it's working fine only for first textarea; remaining textareas remains hidden. Can you please suggest how to handle remaining text areas.